# USB / Bluetooth API for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, macos, bluetooth

Is there a Mac OS X Bluetooth or USB API that's easy to work with (specifically if you want to be able to access a connected iPhone and send/receive information)? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apple "Made for iPhone" Licensing Program gives developers access to technical documentation and hardware components that are used to develop accessories that interact with iPhone. It's the only official way to develop for the iPhone USB interface.

[Apples Made for iPod programme](http://developer.apple.com/ipod/index.html)

Comment: +1, there is that way to get in.  You'll need extra hardware though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at WiFi/Bonjour for connecting to an iPhone from a Mac or PC. Many apps already use this for tasks such as file transfer.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone [doesn't have](http://www.macintouch.com/iphone/faq.html#features) bluetooth file transfer, I'm afraid.  The only way in via USB is through iTunes; the iPhone doesn't present itself to the OS as a mass storage device.